# Error at accessing database table data in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a database table and I am listing it into a jsp table. I have author names, titles, dates and quantities in it. I want to make an edit function and to display the current id with its corresponding data. I have managed to access all the data, but the author and the title. I am using the same method, accesing them through javascript, but it gives me this error for title and author:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: MP is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`
where "MP" is an author name. I don't understand how the code manages to see the current author's name, but not display it in the edit field and thus triggering the error... I have simplified the function down there, to see what is triggering my error...

```
  <c:forEach var="book" items="${bookAttribute}">
    <tr id="book_${book.id}">
        <td><c:out value="${book.author}"/></td>



 <button class="button" id="editButton_${book.id}" type="submit" name="editButton" onclick="editBooks(${book.author})">
</button>




function editBooks(author) {
        document.getElementById("authorText").value = author;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least one problem and potentially two (but you haven't provided enough information to determine the second).

First, you are attempting to pass a string into your `editBooks()` function like this:

```
onclick="editBooks(${book.author})"
```

In the case of the author named `MP`, the result looks like this:

```
onclick="editBooks(MP)"
```

As you can see, there is no variable defined as `MP` so you see that error.

To fix put quotes around the interprelation like this:

```
onclick="editBooks('${book.author}')"
```

The second problem may be related to this code:

```
document.getElementById("authorText").value = author;
```

If the element with the id of `authorText` is NOT an `HTMLInputElement`, this code won't do what you expect. Only `HTMLInputElement`s have a value property. Elements like `<div>`s have `textContent` properties. So depending on the type of element you are putting the author's name into, you may need to change this:

```
document.getElementById("authorText").value = author;
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById("authorText").textContent = author;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked with using '${book.author}' only!